# How to make one Midnight Commander tab a shell?

Tags: midnight-commander

Is it possible to turn one (either left or right) tab of MC into a shell?

So I can type command in shell and see a full output and see the directories and files at once?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check these sites. I'm sorry, I posted here because this question occured in scope of programming: I need to make a lot of small edits in quite extensive source tree.

Comment: Don't apologize, no harm done :) Just that on those sites you might get some help quicker than here.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://midnight-commander-user-discussion.2516130.n2.nabble.com/How-to-switch-two-gt-single-panel-modes-td7574854.html) post on MC's user discussion you can do something like this by pressing M-t (M stands for meta) several times.